# Splashscreen not working

Tags: blackberry

The below splashscreen is not displaying correctly. It works fine when I push just the splashscreen but not when I push the splashscreen and then another screen. Welcome screen is the splashscreen.

So this works -

```
pushScreen(new WelcomeScreen());
```

But not this -

```
pushScreen(new WelcomeScreen());
pushScreen(new MenuScreen());
```

In the second scenario the menuscreen is displayed straight away but not the splashscreen.

Here is the splash screen code - two classes.

```
package screens;

import com.src.driver.Driver;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

public class WelcomeScreen extends SplashScreen {

    public WelcomeScreen() {
        super(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png"), 5);
        //normal mainscreen items:
        //setTitle("SplashScreen Test");
        //add(new LabelField("HelloWorld!"));
    }
}

package screens;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.src.driver.Driver;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class SplashScreen extends MainScreen {

    Bitmap popup;
    SplashScreen screen = this;
    private Timer splashTimer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask splashTask;
    int count = 0;
    int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = Display.getHeight();
    int yCoord;
    int xCoord;
    boolean showSplash = true;
    boolean splashDisplayed = false;

    public SplashScreen(Bitmap popup, final int seconds) {
        this.popup = popup;
        xCoord = (screenWidth - popup.getWidth()) / 2;
        yCoord = (screenHeight - popup.getHeight()) / 2;

        splashTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if (showSplash && !splashDisplayed) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == seconds * 10) {
                        showSplash = false;
                        splashDisplayed = true;
                        splashTimer.cancel();
                        invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        splashTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(splashTask, 100, 100);

    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        if (showSplash && !splashDisplayed) {
            graphics.drawBitmap(xCoord, yCoord, popup.getWidth(), popup.getHeight(), popup, 0, 0);
            //draw border, delete if not needed:
            //graphics.setColor(0xcccccc);
            //graphics.drawRect(xCoord, yCoord, popup.getWidth(), popup.getHeight());
        }
    }

    protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
        showSplash = true;
        invalidate();
        super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
    }

    //allow user to dismiss splash screen:
    protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();

    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();
    }

    protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
        return DismissSplash();
    }

    private boolean DismissSplash() {
        if (showSplash) {
            showSplash = false;
            splashDisplayed = true;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that MenuScreen is pushed immediately after WelcomeScreen.  You will need to put in some kind of mechanism that waits for WelcomeScreen to "finish" before pushing the MenuScreen.

Maybe create a Listener object that is passed into WelcomeScreen.  Then when WelcomeScreen "finishes" it would call the Listener (e.g. `myListener.splashScreenFinished()`).  Then the implementation of the Listener would create and push the MenuScreen.

This might look something like this:

```
interface MyListener {
    public void splashScreenFinished();
}
```

```
class MyApp implements MyListener {
    ...
    public void splashScreenFinished() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pushScreen(new MenuScreen());
            }
        });
    }

    public void startupApp() {
        pushScreen(new WelcomeScreen(this));
    }
    ...
}
```

```
class WelcomeScreen {
    private MyListener l;

    public WelcomeScreen(MyListener listener) {
        l = listener;
        ...
    }

    protected onSplashTimerDone() {
        if (l != null)
            l.splashScreenFinished();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, seem to be almost there now. Once the splashscreen has finished displaying a blank white screen is displayed, even though I am pushing the menuscreen. If I click the blackberry options screen and close the menu screen the menu screen is displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure why the menuscreen is not being pushed to the screen because it does run the code which pushes the menuscreen.

Comment: hmm, maybe the implementation of `splashScreenFinished()` needs to wrap the `pushScreen(new MainScreen())` in an `invokeLater()` call?

Comment: ok, but does'nt that mean I need to code pushScreen(new MainScreen()) in a seperate thread ?

Comment: not really, you can just create an anonymous class (see my edits above).

Comment: I've tried that and now the splash screen is appearing briefly ( < 1 second) and then the main menu screen is displayed. Should I add a Thread.sleep into the runnable ? Thanks again

Comment: Without seeing code, can't be sure, but it sounds like you're calling `splashScreenFinished` too soon.  Check your logic / debug to see when you are calling that method -- you shouldn't call it until you are ready for the `MenuScreen` to display.

Comment: Its working, I'm not calling  onSplashTimerDone(); from the run method of splashscreen. Thanks for the help